# Is There a Way to Make Vim Provide an Error Message Whenever it Beeps?

Tags: message

I know that when vim beeps at me it is generally telling me I did something wrong.  Sometimes it displays a helpful error message and sometimes it does not.  Is there a way to make it always show a message giving a reason for a beep, or is there a way to ask it for one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not completely true that vim uses the beeps (or bells, as it calls them) only in errors.
There are many events that can trigger the bells, only some of them are errors.

You can custom the bell to ring only in errors (or whenever you want), by setting the value of 'belloff'.

All the error messages should be shown when they are happening, other things that make vim beeps are probably not errors.

You can read more about customing the beeps and when they happens here:

```
help belloff
help errorbells
help visualbell
```

Comment: Thanks, @Omri Sarig, for the helpful explanation and references, from which I learned that the answer to whether there is a way to get a message on every beep, error or not, explaining the reason, seems to be "no", based on the following at `help errorbells` "....the bell will be used always for a lot of errors without a message...."